# In Javascript, how to execute a function on elements of two seqs concurently?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iteration, loops, underscore.js

In Javascript, what is the best way for iterating concurrently on two arrays and calling a function on the two running elements? For example:

```
var a = [1, 2, 3];
var b = [11, 12, 13];
function my_func() { /* some custom function */}
```

The code should execute my_func 3 times, like this:

```
my_func(1,11);
my_func(2,12);
my_func(3,13);
```

How can I achieve that without defining a new function, but using jQuery/underscore api?

Comment: Do you realize that this `[1 2 3]` and `[11 12 13]` are not valid javascript syntax?  You need commas between the elements if you intend for them to be an array of numbers.

Comment: Thanks @jfriend00. Those days, I am switching a lot between javascript and clojure (my 2 favorite languages).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For example, this way (using underscore.js)?

```
_.each( _.zip(a,b), my_func );

function my_func( pair ){
  alert( pair[0] + pair[1] );
}
```

Or:

```
_.each( _.zip(a,b), function( pair ){
  my_func( pair[0], pair[1] );
  // or: my_func.apply( null, pair );
});

function my_func( a, b ){
  alert( a + b );
}
```

-

```
function wrapply( func, thisObj ){
  return function( args ){
    return func.apply( thisObj, args );
  }
}

var add = wrapply( function(a,b){ return a+b; });
alert( add([1,2]) );
```

Comment: I really like the code using apply. Is there any other jQuery/underscore method that overcome the need for apply. I mean writing something like:    _.each_apply(_.zip(a,b), my_func);

Comment: Hi, i added an example function for this, testing it is your homework :)

Answer (score 3):

Well, straight-forward JavaScript is pretty good at doing this. Just use a standard `for` loop, assuming that your `a` arrays and `b` array have the same length.

```
for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    my_func(a[i], b[i]);
}
```

jQuery also provides an `.each()` method that can make operating on *one* sequence very easy. Operating on *two* just takes a bit more code.

```
$.each(a, function(i, aItem) { my_func(aItem, b[i]); });
```

And if you want to use a `zip` operation, you can use the [jQueryArrayUtils plugin](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-utils/wiki/JqueryArrayUtils).

```
$.zip(a, b).each(function() {
    var aItem = this[0];
    var bItem = this[1];
    my_func(aItem, bItem);
});
```

Being a fan of Python, this last method seems particularly nice to me. But honestly, if you're not going to do anything more complicated than calling `my_func`, then you may as well just use a normal `for` loop.

Comment: +1. I think the plain `for` loop is the best approach here. As easy to write and as easy to read as a library-based solution (easier than the jQuery `$.each()` method), _and_ more efficient at runtime...

Answer (score 0):

```
[1,2,3].forEach(function(e, i, arr){my_func(e, arr[i]);}, [11,12,13]);
```

jQuery version:

```
$.each(a, function(index, value) { 
    my_func(value, b[index]);
});
```